# Atomic operation on PriorityBlockingQueue

Tags: java, multithreading, locks

I want to know which thread has enqued to the PriorityBlockingQueue first.

I am creating a PriorityBlockingQueue of type myNode. Each myNode has an AtomicBoolean lock and a Priority field. myNode implements comparable based on priority.

I have multiple threads running. Every thread, once started, will create its myNode and adds its node to the PriorityBlockingQueue.

Now I want to handle things differently on the first thread do an add operation on PriorityBlockingQueue. 
I can check if the queue is empty to know this and then enq, but there is a possibility that two threads can simultaneously check for empty and do the enq operation.
Even index of this node after enq does not help here because of the priority constrain.

So, is there something that can give me the functionality in PriorityBlockingQueue similar to getAndSet() in AtomicBoolean.

Or can you suggest me any other alternatives..

Thanks,

Comment: My immediate thought is to develop a subclass of `PriorityBlockingQueue<MyNode>` that handles enqueuing differently if the queue is empty. Wouldn’t expect it to be hard to make, but haven’t worked it out in detail in my mind.

Comment: Is it the first add operation ever performed on the queue that should differ, or is it an add operation on an empty queue? I’m asking because the queue may run empty several times in its life time and be filled again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Its the first add on operation whenever the queue is empty.

Comment: I’m looking a bit at the `PriorityBlockingQueue` documentation and source code. You will need to provide your own synchronization of the `add` method since the lock the class is using is private and thus not accessible in a subclass. When you provide your own synchronization, you can do it outside the queue if you find this more convenient than using a subclass, you have both options.